# UNRESOLVED: Integrating Piece-wise Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, piecewise-continuity

**UNRESOLVED**

So given a function under the following conditions:

$$f(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
3t && t\lt 3\\
10 && 3\le t\le 6\\
-\frac{1}{3}t + 6 && 6\le t \le 9
\end{cases}$$

How would I go about finding the area of
$$ \int_0^9 f(t) \ dt$$

My logic has been to iterate each piece for the given condition i.e. 
Evaluate $3t$ from the $t$ value $0$ to $3$ et. cetera.

So for 
$\ \ 0-3 = 18,\\
\ \ 3-6 = 40,\\
\ \ 6-9 = 14$

Therefore $ \int_0^9 f(t) \ dt = 72$?

**Another idea** of mine, simplify the formulae for each condition which is $\frac{8(t+6)}{3}$ and then integrate $f(t)$ as $$\int_0^9\frac{8(t+6)}{3}dt=252$$

Comment: Your logic is correct, however you have computed the integrals incorrectly

Comment: What is it that I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Your function must be given as $3\le t < 6$. You know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^9\!f(t)\ dt&=\int_0^3\!f(t)\ dt+\int_3^6\!f(t)\ dt+\int_6^9\!f(t)\ dt\\
&=\int_0^3\!3t\ dt+\int_3^6\!10\ dt+\int_6^9\!\left(-\frac{1}{3}t + 6\right)\ dt\\
&=\frac32t^2\big|_0^3+10t\big|_3^6-\frac16t^2\big|_6^9+6t\big|_6^9\\
&=\frac32\times9+30-\frac{9^2-6^2}{6}+18\\
&=42
\end{align}